# Ajax response in DIV

Tags: ajax

Hello I would like to slightly modify the below script so that it outputs the response     to a div rather than a alert see bold section. Any help appreciated!

```
function processResponse() {
    if (gateway.readyState == 4 && gateway.status == 200) {
        alert("Done loading!\n\nThe response from the PHP script was: "+gateway.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: //our function
function runPHPScript() {
      gateway = startAjax();
      if (!gateway)
      return;
        else {
         gateway.open('GET', 'GetChatter.php', true);
         gateway.onreadystatechange = function() { processResponse(1); }
         gateway.send(null);
        }
      
     }

Comment: you can edit your post to update your question and improve it ;) I do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

if the div has an id try something like this:

```
document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = gateway.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function processResponse() { 
    if (gateway.readyState == 4 && gateway.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML = "php script was : " + gateway.responseText;
    } 
}
```

or if using jquery

```
function processResponse() { 
    if (gateway.readyState == 4 && gateway.status == 200) {
        $("#youdivid").html("php script was : " + gateway.responseText);
    } 
}
```